# Query linking many-to-many relationship over several tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle, many-to-many, subclass

I am making a quiz-program. In a quiz I have many participants, but on the other hand participants can enter many quizzes (over time). So I have overcome this many-to-many relationship with a linking table. So far I can understand.. now for the difficulty for me: a participant can either be a group, or a single player.

So a quiz has a participant (with a linking table) and this participant is either a group which has several persons, or this participant is a player and only one single person.

```
table Quiz : PrimaryKey = quiz_id, (name, date,... )
table QuizParticipant : PrimaryKey = quiz_participant_id, quiz_id 
table ParticipantGroup : PrimaryKey = quiz_participant_id, group_id
table participantPlayer : PrimaryKey = quiz_participant_id, person_id
```

The problem for me is: how do I query all participants of a quiz by quiz_id, and preferably sort them by type (group or player)?

Tips on how to google this stuff are usefull as well :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an interesting design decision. The way you proceed can shape your entire application.

My advice is to record the participant type within each occurance of participation. This would be either "GROUP" or "PLAYER" and would define whether the ParticipantID referred to a GroupID or a PlayerID. This will result in the cleanest database design and application logic in the end.

So your tables look like:

Quiz (QuizID,QuizName)
QuizParticipation (ParticipationID, ParticipantType, ParticipantID)
Group (GroupID,GroupName)
GroupMembers(GroupID,PlayerID)
Player(PlayerID,Name)

You might need to make a custom constraint to ensure that duplicates cannot be created within the ParticipantID and ParticipationType combined fields of the QuizParticipation table, or manage the generation of primary keys carefully.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to always link your quizzes to groups (many to many) and treat single players as a group of 1. So your groups are linked to players (also many to many)

Answer (score 0):

If a person can belong to many groups and a group can have many people, that's another many to many relationship.  Since you know how to create these linking tables, create one for this relationship.